# Transparent buttons cannot be clicked in Firefox and IE but are working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am developing something like Spot the difference game but I am using Javascript to do the spots.

Here goes: I have some transparent buttons(css style background transparent) that I have positioned with CSS and when I click on the transparent buttons, the spots will appear(using style.visibility). The thing is, this javascript is working fine in both Google Chrome and Safari but I don't know why the buttons are not working in IE and Firefox.

Can you help me with this? I am puzzled by this problem. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't post the code involved, it'll be very hard for people to help you.

Comment: It would be easier to solve issues, if there was some code to see. The most critical parts of the code at least.

Comment: It's a bad idea to have those elements that can be clicked in the HTML page themselves. This leads to fraud and cheating. Better have a communication with the server and check for the x and y coordinates of the mouse

Comment: I am sorry but I can't seem to edit my own post. Is it alright for me to post the codes at comment?

Comment: In Firefox: If a button contains nothing, it should have width and height defined in CSS-rules (or by attributes). Why use hidden buttons on page?

Comment: The same issue in IE. These browsers don't have a pre-defined size value for `button` -elements.

Comment: This question has been resolved. I set the width and height for the buttons and they are working now. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me in all browsers

```
    css:
    button{
       display:block;
       width:500px;
       height:500px;
       background-color:transparent;
       border: 1px solid #000;
     }
```

```
    javascript:
    document.getElementById('but').onclick=function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor="#000"
    }
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/7tg3h/1/